# Linux task in the background finishes

Tags: linux, command-line, command, uibackgroundtask

I have got a Linux task that finishes and prints:

```
[6]- Done
```

I have noticed that in the past it would print:

```
[6]+ Done
```

Is there any difference between `+` and `-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`man bash`** states:

> In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the current job is always flagged with a +, and the previous job with a -.

Therefore, the command with '+' is the most recent command sent to the background.